# chmod 4755 (rwsr-xr-x) gives (rwxrwxrwx)

Tags: permissions, root, chmod

I want to get the permissions of a program, call_shellcode (which calls shellcode), to be set to -rwsr-xr-x. When I run:

```
sudo chmod 4755 call_shellcode
```

the permissions for some reason is still set at -rwxrwxrwx

[image: Picture showcasing permissions]

I am trying to get the root shell, but when I execute the program I get a normal shell. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 (32-bit) in VirtualBox

Comment: Is this file on an NTFS partition or something like that?

Comment: Please ***don't post pictures of your problem!*** Post it as text instead.

Comment: It is in a shared folder between host and guest for the VM

Comment: Who is the owner of the file? you can find this out by running ls -l on the directory.

Comment: Is that really the only error message you get? Nothing about `Operation not permitted`?

Comment: Yeah it only shows what is there

Comment: please [edit] your question, and add the result of `ls -l` in that directory

Answer (score 3):

You are running `gcc` as root for some strange reason, but then you run the `chmod` as your regular user. You don't have [permission to change the rights of `call_shellcode` since you compiled it as root, and therefore the permissions remain unchanged.

Don't compile as root! Don't do *anything* as root unless you have to.

Comment: I just tried `gcc -o call_shellcode call_shellcode.c` without the sudo and it still doesnt work

Comment: @JamesTan - the file `call_shellcode` already exists and owned by `root`, you need to `sudo rm call_shellcode` before running the `gcc` as regular user

Answer (score 0):

From `man chmod`:

```
SETUID AND SETGID BITS

   chmod clears the set-group-ID bit of a regular file if the file's group
   ID  does  not  match the user's effective group ID or one of the user's
   supplementary group IDs, unless the user  has  appropriate  privileges.
   Additional restrictions may cause the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits
   of MODE or RFILE to be ignored.  This behavior depends  on  the  policy
   and  functionality of the underlying chmod system call.  When in doubt,
   check the underlying system behavior.
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Zanna's question, I moved the files out of the shared folder and now the permissions are set correctly.